# Saber si existe un registro en una base de datos MySQL con consulta preparada en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buenos días estoy intentado básicamente eso, comprobar si existe un registro en mi base de datos de usuarios pasandole el correo que es la primary key. Tengo entendido que el método mysqli_stmt_execute devuelve true o false dependiendo si encuentra o no resultados (https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php). El caso es que le pase lo que le pase siempre me devuelve 1, true. Os dejo el código. Sobre el método nuevaConexión() funciona perfectamente, inserto, borro, etc, sin problemas.

```
// Método para saber si existe un registro por el correo
static function exitePersona($correo) {
    // Abro la conexion
    self::nuevaConexcion();

    // Preparo la sentencia SQL
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare(self::$conexion, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $val1);

    // Valores de la sentencia
    $val1 = $correo;

    // Ejecución de la sentencia
    $exite = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    // Cerrar la conexión
    mysqli_close(self::$conexion);

    return $exite;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero en principio no, si lo hago así funciona a la perfección, pero la web es vulnerable mediante inyección SQL, necesito ayuda con la consulta preparada.

Comment: La documentación no dice que devuelve true si encuentra resultados.

Comment: @LuisQuesadaRomero edité la publicación que te referencié para el tema de consultas preparadas :)

Answer (score 1):

yo lo hago de la siguiente manera, antes de realizar la inserción realizo la validación y para verificar si ya existe un registro lo hago con mysqli_num_rows, quedaría algo como esto:

```
// Preparo la sentencia SQL
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare(self::$conexion, $query);
$respuesta = mysqli_query($stmt);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($respuesta)>0)
     {
         // Si es mayor a cero imprimimos que ya existe el correo
        echo "Ya existe el correo que intenta registrar";
    }else{
   //Aquí inserto los datos si no hay un registro
}
```

Comment: El tema es que el OP quiere constituir su consulta de forma preparada, te invito a checar la que marque como duplicada

Comment: Si lo siento no había visto eso.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. He modificado algo el código y ahora funciona perfectamente. He usado mysqli_stmt_num_rows() para leer cuantas filas me devuelve la consulta y va perfecto ahora.

```
// Método para saber si existe un registro por el correo
static function exitePersona($correo) {
    // Abro la conexion
    self::nuevaConexcion();

    // Preparo la sentencia SQL
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare(self::$conexion, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $val1);

    // Valores de la sentencia
    $val1 = $correo;

    // Ejecución de la sentencia
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    
    // Almacenar el resultado
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    
    // Compruebo las filas que trae la consulta, si es 0 no existe el registro
    printf("Número de filas: %d.\n", mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt));
    
    // Cierro la sentencia
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    
    // Cerrar la conexión
    mysqli_close(self::$conexion);

}
```